# Rename files randomly but without repetition

Tags: scripting, rename, mv, random

Suppose i have a folder
with a lot of file names
some very strange and nonsense
I want to rename it like

```
File-1
File-2
File-3
..
```

I have tried this(echo is for tryng)

```
for name in *; do echo mv $name File-`echo $(( RANDOM % (10 - 5 + 1 ) + 1 ))`;done
```

But give me a  lot of duplicates

```
mv bio1 file-3
mv memory23 file-1
mv mernad file-3
mv nio2 file-4
mv nun3 file-4
```

Comment: What is `10 - 5 + 1` supposed to be? (What's the meaning of the magic number here?)

Comment: Give me random value between 1 and 5 the problem is duplicates

Comment: random but in order...?!?!? please describe the problem ... more ...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could maybe use `shuf` (from the GNU coreutils package), which generates *permutations* rather than individual random samples - something like

```
for f in *; do read i; echo mv -- "$f" "file-$i"; done < <(shuf -i 1-10)
```

or (perhaps better) shuffle the *filenames* - and then simply rename them sequentially

```
i=1; shuf -z -e -- * | while IFS= read -rd '' f; do echo mv -- "$f" "File-$((i++))"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pre=file ;
for old in * ;
 do new=`xxd -l 16 -ps /dev/urandom` ;
 while [ -f "$pre-$new" ] ; do new=`xxd -l 16 -ps /dev/urandom` ; done ;
 mv "$old" "$pre-$new" ;
done ;
```

`xxd` is a binary which usually comes with: `vim-common` package.

`xxd` **-l** attribute refers to the random length you want.

`xxd` **-ps** is to get postscript plain hexdump style names, for example: a4c794f3861f5d3e36ca9b0afd15ceab

`/dev/urandom` is the linux kernel pseudo-random numbers generator, if you don't have it, just write: `mknod -m 444 /dev/urandom c 1 9`

the `while [ -f "$pre-$new" ]` command **guarantees**, that no other file has the same name.

the `[` command usually comes in `coreutils` package.

the `pre` variable is to choose a name prefix. If you don't want a prefix, you can leave it blank: `pre= ;`

For example:

```
file 1
file 2
file 3
file 4
file 5
```

With `pre=file` becomes:

```
file-062b9bcde91f1c56084956d175cfdfa3
file-3e7ec1bd5324a485a3402b106d320f73
file-648cf4550c70b2531350f231670fc982
file-074b2828b004f45581784ff1705c7ff3
file-481be2bb21f4b1e637293ae0ecf14f74
```

Answer (score 1):

Random might return duplicate value.
How about generating numbers in sequence ?

```
count=0
for name in *; do count=`expr $count + 1` ; echo mv $name File-$count;done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your file names in order (ie. File-1 -> File-n) in the end, you should do them sequentially.  --

```
count=0; for i in * ; do mv $i file-${count}; ((count++)); done
```