Rename file and convert to lowercase
This command is to rename files using uuidgen:
zmv '(*)(.*)' '`uuidgen | head -c 8`$2'

Could someone show how to convert resulting string to lowercase?

What's $2 there? Is this supposed to be used in a shell script?

$2 is the filename extension

And where is that set? Please make sure your questions can stand on their own, don't assume we will have read your previous ones. If this needs to be run in a script, let us know. And you generally want to avoid using \command`, use the more powerful $(command)` instead.

In zsh, you don't actually need the external head command - you can nest a command substitution $(uuidgen) inside a parameter expansion, and use either the left or right padding flag to truncate it (I can't think of a reason why it matters which), ex.
 % print -rl ${(r:8:)$(uuidgen)}
8f2156c6

Then you can just add the Lower or Upper expansion flag as well:
 % print -rl ${(Ur:8:)$(uuidgen)}
28474ED7

So putting it all together:
 % zmv -n '(*)(.*)' '${(Lr:8:)$(uuidgen)}$2'
mv -- a.out bcd3ba17.out
mv -- best.sh e211231c.sh
mv -- file.txt 80e374d5.txt
mv -- hello-world.f 2fbc4d3d.f
mv -- test.sh 1adf8762.sh
mv -- trace.out 4407de16.out

However you should consider using zsh's built in random number generator instead of uuidgen, as demonstrated in this answer to your previous question.

And you don't need uuidgen when zsh has builtin support for generating random numbers in any base 2 to 36 (where using the L parameter expansion flag (not modifier, though you can also use the :l and :u csh-style modifiers here) was shown).

@StéphaneChazelas thanks - I knew I as going to get stuff wrong ...

Note that $RANDOM has a short range (only 15 bits) and is not unpredictable, unlike uuidgen. Predictability might not be a concern here since the output is only 32 bits, but do beware that $RANDOM is not suitable anywhere security might be a concern.

many ways - one that's easy:
zmv '*(.*)' '`uuidgen | head -c 8 |tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"`$1'


Would that actually work? With that quoting? Looks like you are passing the output of zmv to tr there. I suspect you mean something like zmv '(*)(.*)' "$(uuidgen | head -c 8 |tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')$2".

@terdon you'd want single rather than double quoting in this context I think - so that the expression is evaluated once per-filename by zmv rather than by the current shell

@steeldriver I don't use zsh so I don't know if zmv does some special magic, but I would expect single quotes to turn it into a string. Don't you need the current shell to substitute $(command) with the output of command?

@terdon the current shell would only substitute once though, so that zmv would attempt to rename all the files to the same truncated uuid. So yes you need zmv to do some special magic - it would probably be more idiomatic to let it do the case conversion and truncation as well via parameter expansion flags ex. zmv -n '(*)(.*)' '${(Lr:8:)$(uuidgen)}$2'

Sounds like you should post an answer, @steeldriver. I really don't know the first thing about zmv and even had to look up how to enable it when I tested this answer.
